# jquery ui tabs: how to call a function in the parent page from an external URL in a tab

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

Just like the question title says:

I've got a standard jquery ui tab set. One tab is to another php file, from which i would like to be able to call a function with an argument on the parent page. Can't figure out how to do it.

Code in external page loaded into the tab:

```
<script language="javascript">
function doSomething(){
    parent.dummyfunction("Hello world!");
}
</script>
<input type='button' value='use recipe' onClick='javascript:doSomething()'>
```

and on the parent, where the tabs are defined, I have:

```
<script language="javascript">
function dummyfunction(whatever){
    alert(whatever);
}
</script>
```

Thank so much for looking

Answer (score 0):

OK I've figured it out. The jquery ui tabs code loads the external file into the target div as flat html. So instead of needing to call a middle-man function (like the doSomething function in the above example), we just call dummyfunction directly, even though the function is not defined on the external page.